# A noun which describes an object that fulfills a condition?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, programming

I'm currently working on my bachelor thesis in the major of Information Systems and I'm coding a small tool, which analyses other programs based on pre-defined conditions.

So now I'm looking for an English noun, which describes **"an object that fulfils a condition"**.

For example a condition could possibly check the type of an object. Like "is object x of type Integer?". I'm looking for a noun describing *x*.

Is it possible to use the word *"trigger"* or something like *"fulfiller"* in this context?

Which word fits best?

Comment: I believe you mean "analyzes". But your explanation is too brief anyway, to be able to choose between those two words. What do you mean "based on" and "pre-defined conditions"? Trigger is of course a more natural word but...

Comment: Could you please be more specific? _Trigger_ might work, but it's too hard to tell from the information given. Perhaps a concrete example would help?

Comment: A condition could possibly check the type of an object. Like "is object x of type Integer?". I'm looking for a noun describing "x".

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of "passing" a test?

Comment: @moss I do not believe the OP meant *analyzes*, that is merely a US spelling for the same word, elsewhere in the world 's' is more acceptable than 'z' in similar situations,  http://grammarist.com/spelling/analyse-analyze/

Comment: Are you looking for *predicate*?

Comment: @Unsliced Oh sorry, it just looked like the plural of 'analysis' to me. The 'z' spelling does help disambiguate that.

Comment: @moss it might avoid the ambiguity but to many eyes, including mine, *analyze* just looks **wrong**!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nouns like *trigger, fulfiller, satisfier* all have problems as words to describe *x* in the question “Is object *x* of type Integer?” or in similar questions.  In the question as just shown, *x* is a ***[formal argument](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_argument#Parameters_and_arguments)*** or ***formal parameter*** that stands for a name or value to be filled in whenever the question is instanced.

In a specific question instance, where *x* has been replaced with some object or an object identifier, then the candidate object or its identifier might be called a ***solution*** (as previously suggested) if it obviously satisfied the predicate, or might be called a ***candidate*** or a ***putative solution*** or ***proposed solution*** if it's less obvious.

In the somewhat-analogous case of [molecular docking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docking_%28molecular%29), the following terminology is used:

> *Receptor* or *host* or *lock* – The "receiving" molecule, most commonly a protein or other biopolymer.
>   *Ligand* or *guest* or *key* – The complementary partner molecule which binds to the receptor.

By analogy, one might refer to predicates as receptors, hosts, or locks, and to corresponding candidates as ligands, guests, or keys.  Extending the analogy slightly, a candidate might be referred to as a ***[supplicant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supplicant#Noun)***.

Comment: Oh, candidate is great for meaning an object that is under consideration for meeting a condition.

Answer (score 0):

The common term used in mathematics and other related subjects is "***satisfies***". A condition is satisfied by an object or when an event occurs and produces a certain outcome.

That which satisfies the condition is the solution (or the root of the equation depending on the context). You can also say "best fit".

I can help you better if you can reference a couple of sentences that occur before the sentence in which you want to use the word and a couple of sentences that occur after.

Comment: That means that the corresponding noun is "satisfier"?

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "satisfier" used in that way. In fact, several standard English dictionaries that I've just checked (ODO, Chambers, Longman) do not even list it as a word.

Comment: @a.ha I edited the answer. Check if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

*Qualifier*. Something that qualifies. As in someone who passes a qualifying round of competition.

I am not entirely sure if your are looking for a word that means it does meet the condition or it is under consideration for the condition, but I think qualifier works fine either way. The only annoying thing is that it has the alternate meaning of "modifier".

Other ones I thought of were *match* and *fit*, but those words have many other uses so they might not work for you.